# OBD2 to USB Cable for Windows 10

Tags: obd-ii, computer, software

One could put an argument that this question is about software and not mechanics, however now-days everything is computerized (including cars and their diagnostic tools) so I believe this question belongs here as this is where one intuitively look for such an answer.

I have recently [bought this cable (ELM327 OBD2)](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/New-V1-5-ELM327-OBD2-OBD-II-CAN-BUS-Diagnostic-Interface-Scanner-ST-UK-Stock-UK/181734879451?_trksid=p2141725.c100338.m3726&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20150313114020%26meid%3D43d9af17ad4d4e03ae12ed3c19c9783c%26pid%3D100338%26rk%3D8%26rkt%3D30%26sd%3D141683045885) but was unable to use it with Windows 10. Windows would detect the cable (USB to COM), but driver under system would have triangle with exclamation mark which indicates that there is something wrong with driver. When trying to update driver windows would give message that this is the latest driver.

I have tried using 4 different diagnostic programs and all of them would fail with messages similar to `Unable to establish connection to COM port` or `nothing is plugged in`, which in my opinion indicate that cable (or driver) is incompatible with Windows 10. (Cable was connected to the car and car had ignition on)

This question is not about how to make my cable work with Windows 10 but rather 
**Does anyone know of OBD2 to USB cable that has drivers and works with Windows 10?**

Comment: If you need a VW/Audi scan tool _witih_ full ODB2 compatibility with other cars, [Ross Tech](http://www.ross-tech.com/index.html) sells the best product you can buy.  Of course, it's a little pricey if you don't have a VW.

Comment: ODB2 compatibility is not the problem. The problem is the missing driver for windows 10. (the elm adaptor speaks ODB II on one side, then has an active part and a second connection to USB | BT | Wifi). In this posters case (s)he has the USB version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use a the Canbus to USB adaptor (not a cable!) ?
The elm327 comes in at least three flavours:

- One with an USB connection.
- One with an bluetooth connection.
- One with an Wifi connection.

I just ordered the third because it uses ancient but widespread IP v4 to set up a connection, making it usuable with almost any computer.
<sup>(Almost since it might be challenging on iphones and similar unless jail broken).</sup>

The alternatives both require special drivers and I am not convinced that those will be updated, neither in time (e.g. not yet available for your current OS) or not at all (e.g. when you want to use it over a decade with then current equipment).

Having written all that, lets actually try to solve your problem.

1. The obvious way: If you do not have the drivers for windows 10 then do not use windows 10. Use a different OS. (Hint: Always wait a few months before upgrading to the newest of the newest).
2. Failing that: Set up a VM on your laptop and pass though the USB connection. This is trivial with software sunch as VMwave workstation (free 30 day trial). There are also plenty of other free hypervisors on the market which do that. Just mentioning WMware workstation because that is what I used.

Both of these work, though the second might be a lot of work unless you are familiar with setting up the hypervisor and installing an OS. In addition to that you would need a CoA to run the second (older) copy of windows in a VM. Which makes it only interesting if you want to use one laptop for everything.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, just to clarify you have bought this one? http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/like/231553464641?adgroupid=13585920426&hlpht=true&hlpv=2&rlsatarget=kwd-75951458106&adtype=pla&ff3=1&lpid=122&poi=&ul_noapp=true&limghlpsr=true&ff19=0&device=c&chn=ps&campaignid=207297426&crdt=0&ff12=67&ff11=ICEP3.0.0-L&ff14=122&viphx=1&ops=true&ff13=80 How does it connect via wifi to laptop? one would still need a driver for Windows right?

Comment: I have ordered [this one](http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B014A54VR8?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00). (No proper amazon.nl site, and amazon.De -> NL shipments tend to be faster than amazon.co.uk to NL shipments). ETA today (though it has not arrived yet). Sadly that means no practical experience with it yet, but I did look around before ordering and thus I knew of the three available types.

Comment: I would appreciate if you would update post when it arrives. Thanks Hennes.

Comment: Got the device on Saturday. Tested on a Skoda Yeti and a Skoda Fabia. Just plug it in and turn the ignition switch to power on. Connected to a laptop (trivial to do) and tested with some free demo software. Worked as a charm. Tried it on a BMW X3 but could not find the ODB connector. (There was something similar to where the manual said the port should be, but it was not the right plug. Pulled really hard at it expecting it to be a cover over the plug but could not looses it without pulling everything apart).

Still, 2 out of 3 test went well and were trivial to set up.

Comment: Thanks Hennes. I Appreciate the effort. Could you add link to the one you bought in your answer.

Comment: I could, but it seems to be a generic device based on the ELM327 chip. I suspect any such device will behave the same.